# Pygame Image Collision?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make when my image (the cat) goes over the square the background will change, but it is not doing anything at the moment, could someone please help. I have a range radius but that does not seem to work. The cat is the hero.

Is something wrong with the rectangle, should I make it into a definition instead of a variable?

Help!

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("A Heros Journy")

GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
NAVYBLUE = (0, 0, 128)

hero = pygame.image.load("cat.png")
herox = 10
heroy = 10

DISPLAYSURF.fill(GREEN)
def main():
    global herox, hero, heroy
    mouseClicked = False

    boxx = 225
    boxy = 225
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(GREEN)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(hero, (herox, heroy))
    while True:
        box = pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (boxx, boxy, 50, 50))
        for event in pygame.event.get():

             if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                 herox, heroy = event.pos
                 DISPLAYSURF.fill(GREEN)
                 DISPLAYSURF.blit(hero, (herox, heroy))

             elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                 herox, heroy = event.pos
                 mouseClicked = True

             if hero in range(boxx, boxy):
                 DISPLAYSURF.fill(NAVYBLUE)

             if event.type == QUIT:
                 pygame.quit()
                 sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note** This is not a very good solution but it works I'm sure there is a way to make it smaller.

Replace

```
if hero in range(boxx, boxy):
             DISPLAYSURF.fill(NAVYBLUE)
```

with

```
if herox > boxx + 50:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(NAVYBLUE)
elif herox < boxx:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(NAVYBLUE)
if heroy > boxy + 50:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(NAVYBLUE)
elif heroy < boxy:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(NAVYBLUE)
```

This solution should work but it's definitely not the best way to do it.

Comment: I just tested it and it works but it doesn't blit the cat after changing the background so you probably want to fix that. Let me know if you need that code.